# Intuition behind the renewal equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes

So. I've acquired the unenviable task of having to learn renewal theory on my own. I'm finding most of it to be pretty intuitive, except for one thing. The **intuition** behind the renewal equation has completely eluded me.

Every resource I've found so far basically dives right in with something like:

> If $f$ is a function in $[0,\infty)$ bounded on finite intervals and $F$ is a measure on $[0,\infty)$, an equation of the type $Z = f + Z \ast F$ is called a **renewal equation**. If $f$ is directly Riemann integrable, then the solution to this equation is given by... If $F(\infty) < 1$ then the equation is defective and if $F(\infty) > 1$ then the equation is excessive... etc...

But... where does this equation even come from and why is it so important? It's just one possible relation out of many. Is there a natural, simple example to see how it arises in a basic, pure renewal process? I'm having a pretty hard time finding a textbook which does a good job of this. For example, I can derive that if I have a renewal process with renewal function $m(t)$ and interarrival distribution $F$, then

$$ m = F + m \ast F $$

But when I move to more complicated functions besides $F$, I'm no longer sure what the result is saying. For example in the above example, the general solution for renewal equations says that $m$ also has a convolution form involving the measure $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F^n$, where $F^n$ is the distribution of the $n$th renewal time. I can see that this measure is just the renewal function, but I'm having trouble interpreting it.

I know it's asking a lot, but can someone de-mystify some of this? If it helps at all, I have a pretty decent grasp of measure-theoretic probability (but not good enough, apparently) and I'm trying to follow Asmussen's chapter on renewal theory.

Comment: Finding this on the evening before my exam that contains renewal theory, I feel doomed :X

Comment: I don't know if this helps but here is one reference in the discrete setting: http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/RenewalTheory.pdf